# После подключения bootstrap стили к body не работают

Tags: bootstrap

Начала изучать bootstrap. После подключения bootstrap через cdn стили к body в СSS не применяются. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот ссылка на макет `введите сюда код`https://codepen.io/aigeitqo-the-scripter/pen/NWwqEgQ

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: поместите link на свой css после ссылки на bootstrap

Comment: Konst, огромнейшая благодарность. Теперь стили для body отображаются.